# Think Python Chapter 10 Exercise 6 Stuck

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, python-3.x

Exercise:

> Write a function called `is_sorted` that takes a list as a parameter and returns `True` if the list is sorted in ascending order and `False` otherwise. You can assume (as a precondition) that the elements of the list can be compared with the relational operators `<`, `>`, etc.
>
> For example, `is_sorted([1,2,2])` should `return True` and `is_sorted(['b', 'a'])` should `return False`.

So far I have:

```
def is_sorted(stuff):
for i in stuff:
    if stuff[i+1] > stuff[i]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
numbers = [1, 0, 5, 2, 8]

print is_sorted(numbers)
```

But it seems to `return True` every time I change the numbers list around. How do I change this so it works?

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
for i in stuff:
```

Iterates through *items*, not *indices*. If you put `5` or `8` first, you will get an `IndexError`. Also, you `return` if the check passes for the first item, much too early! You can `return False` if *any* are out of order, but *all* must be in order to `return True`.

Instead, try using `enumerate` to get both item and index:

```
def is_sorted(stuff):
    for index, item in enumerate(stuff):
        try:
            if item > stuff[index + 1]:
                return False
        except IndexError:
            return True
```

Alternatively, use `zip` to compare pair wise:

```
def is_sorted(stuff):
    return all(b >= a for a, b in 
               zip(stuff, stuff[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in stuff` will enumerate each of the elements.  What you'd like to do is enumerate the **indices** of the elements, so change the loop to

`for i in range(len(stuff))`

Next, you dont want to return True if you come across a subsequent element greater than the current.  just return True after testing each pair of adjacent elements, so something like:

```
def is_sorted(stuff):    
    for i in range(1,len(stuff)):
        if stuff[i - 1] > stuff[i]:
           return False
    return True
```

Comment: I think you need to dedent `return True` a little further.

Answer (score 0):

Building off @jonrsharpe's answer,

This is a great application of the `itertools` `pairwise` recipe:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None) #or b.next() on Python 2.5 and below
    return izip(a, b)

def is_sorted(iterable):
    return all(a <= b for a,b in pairwise(iterable))
```

This avoids indexed access or slicing, which allows you to operate on generators and greatly reduces memory footprint.

```
is_sorted(xrange(5000000))
```

Unfortunately, it won't help you for infinite generators like `is_sorted(count(0))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're conflating `for item in stuff` with `for i in range(len(stuff))`.

Say `stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

1. With `for item in stuff`, you'd be iterating over each item in `stuff`: 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'.
2. With `for i in range(len(stuff))`, you'd be iterating over each index of `stuff`: 0, 1, 2, 3.

Note that the variable names `item` and `i` are common conventions for these statements but are not mandatory--you can replace `item` and `i` with anything you want. Therefore your 2nd line of code (`for i in stuff`) is executing #1 above, not #2 as you were expecting.

To have your code execute #2, you'd have to use `range(len(stuff)` in your 2nd line of code instead of just `stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I am trying to refine my solution to this problem.

I want to make sure no body sneaks in an integer or a string in a predominantly string or integer list resp. For instance, ['a', 'b', 2]

I wrote a python program for this but it seems to me it is getting a bit unwieldy. Is there any better solution to this?

```
def is_sorted(stuff):
    is_int = 1
    not_int = 0 

if type(stuff[0]) == int:
    of_type = is_int
else:
    of_type = not_int

for i in range(1,len(stuff)):
    if (of_type == is_int and (type(stuff[i - 1]) == int and type(stuff[i]) == int)) or \
                    (of_type == not_int and (type(stuff[i - 1]) == str and type(stuff[i]) == str)): 
        if stuff[i - 1] > stuff[i]:
            return False
    else:
        print "I saw what you did there!"
        return False
return True

print is_sorted(['b', 'a']) //False
print is_sorted(['a', 'b']) //True
print is_sorted([1, 2]) //True
print is_sorted(['a', 'b', 2]) //False; "I saw what you did there!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isSorted(stuff):
    if len(stuff) == 0:
        output = 'True'
    if len(stuff) == 1:
        output = 'True'
    for i in range(0,len(stuff)-1):
        if stuff[i+1] > stuff[i]:
            output = 'True'
        else:
            return False
    return output
```